# How to return most recent element with distinct subquery

Tags: postgresql, join, distinct

I have such query but it returns duplicated rows for same `speaker`

```sql
SELECT 
    "speakers"."id",
    "speakers"."name",
    "speakers"."surname",
    "speakers"."photo_url" as "photoURL",
    "talks"."title" as "lastTalkTitle",
    "talks"."publication_date"::date as "lastTalkDate",
    "talks"."language_id"::uuid as "lastTalkLanguage",
    "conference_groups"."name" as "lastTalkConferenceName",
    CASE WHEN "user_speakers_favourited"."user_id" = '3B3ED15E-788E-447E-B946-BA52E7E90E62' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END as "favourited",
    coalesce(count("talk_ratings"."id") FILTER (WHERE "talk_ratings"."rating_up"),0)::bigint as "ratingUp",
    coalesce(count("talk_ratings"."id") FILTER (WHERE "talk_ratings"."rating_down"),0)::bigint as "ratingDown",
    coalesce(count(DISTINCT "talks"."id"),0)::bigint as "talkCount"
FROM "speakers"
LEFT JOIN "talk_speaker" ON "talk_speaker"."speaker_id" = "speakers"."id" 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON ("talk_speaker"."speaker_id") "talks".* 
    FROM "talk_speaker" 
    LEFT JOIN "talks" ON "talks"."id" = "talk_speaker"."talk_id" 
    ORDER BY "talk_speaker"."speaker_id" DESC, "talks"."publication_date" DESC
    ) as "talks" ON "talks"."id" = "talk_speaker"."talk_id" AND "speakers"."id" = "talk_speaker"."speaker_id" 
LEFT JOIN "conferences" ON "talks"."conference_id" = "conferences"."id"
LEFT JOIN "user_speakers_favourited" ON "user_speakers_favourited"."speaker_id" = "speakers"."id" AND "user_speakers_favourited"."user_id" = '3B3ED15E-788E-447E-B946-BA52E7E90E62'
LEFT JOIN "talk_ratings" ON "talks"."id" = "talk_ratings"."talk_id" AND "talk_speaker"."speaker_id" = "speakers"."id"
LEFT JOIN "conference_groups" ON "conference_groups"."id" = "conferences"."conference_group_id"
GROUP BY "speakers"."id", "talks"."title", "talks"."publication_date", "talks"."language_id", "conference_groups"."name", "conferences"."id", "user_speakers_favourited"."user_id" 
ORDER BY lower("speakers"."surname") ASC, "talks"."publication_date" DESC
```

Query should return most recent `talk` for `speaker`

`talk_speaker` table is pivot table as `talk` can have multiple `speakers` and `speaker` can have multiple `talks`.

thanks in advance for help

Comment: Move this query (without ORDER BY) into CTE, and add ROW_NUMBER() output field with proper partitioning (per speaker?) and ordering (by talk datetime?). In the main query select rows where this row number is 1 (and add ordering if needed).

Comment: unfortunately I do not know what is CTE?

Comment: Common Table Expression. [WITH clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH). [WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

Comment: thank you. It wasn't easy but I managed to do this with WITH and ROW_NUMBER()